# WiFi Direct Service Discovery - Android Service

Tags: android, service, wifi, p2p

I'm trying to develop a chat app on Android using WiFi Direct with service discovery, I tried to build my app on Android's WiFiServiceDiscovery sample: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/d4a1f0619bc6a83d75c7b6686f9015eb7b3cec6c/samples/WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/discovery
The problem is that I want the WiFiServiceDiscoveryActivity to be turned into an Android Service, so it can run discovering peers and notifying users even if the app was closed/paused

So I tried to turn it into an Android Service:

```
public class ConnectAndDiscoverService extends Service implements Handler.Callback, WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener,WiFiDirectServicesFragment.DeviceClickListener{



    /*
     *Service attributes
     */
    public static final String TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE = "available";
    //Our service's name and protocol
    public static final String SERVICE_NAME = "_vicinityapp";
    public static final String SERVICE_REG_TYPE = "_presence._tcp";
    static final int SERVER_PORT = 4142;

    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0x400 + 1;
    public static final int MY_HANDLE = 0x400 + 2;
    private WifiP2pManager manager;

    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private Channel channel;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
    private WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest serviceRequest;

    private Handler handler = new Handler(this);

    public Handler getHandler(){
        return this.handler;
    }
    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }


    public ConnectAndDiscoverService() {
        Log.i(TAG,"Service started");
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter
                .addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter
                .addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        startRegistrationAndDiscovery();

        // servicesList = new WiFiDirectServicesList();
        // getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        //  .add(R.id.container_root, servicesList, "services").commit();

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind");
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    /**
     * This method adds _vicinityapp local service to the network
     * then calls discoverService()
     */
    private void startRegistrationAndDiscovery() {
        Log.i(TAG,"startRegistrationAndDiscovery");

        Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
        record.put(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE, "visible");
        //WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo is A class for storing Bonjour service information that is advertised over a Wi-Fi peer-to-peer setup.
        WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo service = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_REG_TYPE, record);

        //addLocalService Registers our service as a local service in order to be discovered.
        manager.addLocalService(channel, service, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                //What to do if our service got advertised in the local network
                Log.i(TAG,"_vicinityapp Service registered");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int error) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Failed to add a service");
            }
        });

        discoverService();

    }

    /**
     *First discoverService() registers listeners for DNS-SD services
     * Then it creates a service discovery request and initiates service discovery
     */
    private void discoverService() {
        Log.i(TAG,"discoverService");
        //setDnsSdResponseListeners() Registers a callback to be invoked on receiving Bonjour service discovery response.
        manager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(channel,
                new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName,
                                                        String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice srcDevice) {

                        // A service has been discovered here, we need to see if it's our app.
                        if (instanceName.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_NAME)) {

                            // update the UI and add the item the discovered
                            // device.
                            /*WiFiDirectServicesList fragment = (WiFiDirectServicesList) getFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentByTag("services");
                            if (fragment != null) {
                                WiFiDirectServicesList.WiFiDevicesAdapter adapter = ((WiFiDirectServicesList.WiFiDevicesAdapter) fragment
                                        .getListAdapter());
                                WiFiP2pService service = new WiFiP2pService();
                                service.device = srcDevice;
                                service.instanceName = instanceName;
                                service.serviceRegistrationType = registrationType;
                                adapter.add(service);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onBonjourServiceAvailable "
                                        + instanceName);
                            }*/
                        }

                    }
                }, new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {

                    /*
                     * A new TXT record is available. Pick up the advertised
                     * buddy name.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(
                            String fullDomainName, Map<String, String> record,
                            WifiP2pDevice device) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                device.deviceName + " is "
                                        + record.get(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE));
                    }
                });



        //1. Add a service discovery request: addServiceRequest()
        serviceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
        manager.addServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequest,
                new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.i(TAG,"Added service discovery request");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                        Log.i(TAG,"Failed adding service discovery request");
                    }
                });
        //2. Initiating service discovery.
        manager.discoverServices(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service discovery initiated");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service discovery failed");

            }
        });

    }//end of discoverServices

    /**
     *
     * @param msg
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Log.d(TAG, readMessage);
                // (chatFragment).pushMessage("Buddy: " + readMessage);
                break;

            case MY_HANDLE:
                Object obj = msg.obj;
                // (chatFragment).setChatManager((ChatManager) obj);

        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This method connects peers with each other
     * @param service the service you want to connect to
     */
    @Override
    public void connectP2p(WiFiP2pService service) {
        Log.i(TAG,"connectP2P");
        //Wi-Fi P2p configuration for setting up a connection
        WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
        config.deviceAddress = service.device.deviceAddress;//device unique MAC address
        config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
        if (serviceRequest != null)
            manager.removeServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequest,
                    new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                        }
                    });

        manager.connect(channel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.i(TAG,"Connecting to service");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Failed connecting to service");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * After connecting to a P2P group this method is invoked
     * @param p2pInfo
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo p2pInfo) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onConnectionAvailable");
        Thread handler = null;
        /*
         * The group owner accepts connections using a server socket and then spawns a
         * client socket for every client. This is handled by {@code
         * GroupOwnerSocketHandler}


        if (p2pInfo.isGroupOwner) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected as group owner");
            try {
                handler = new GroupOwnerSocketHandler(
                        ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler());
                handler.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Failed to create a server thread - " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected as peer");
            handler = new ClientSocketHandler(
                    ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler(),
                    p2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress);
            handler.start();
        }
        chatFragment = new WiFiChatFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_root, chatFragment).commit();
        statusTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
    }
    /**
     * This method changes the original device name
     * to the user's username
     * @param username registered username
     */
    public void changeDeviceName(String username){

        try{
            Log.i(TAG,"Changing name!!");

            Method m = manager.getClass().getMethod(
                    "setDeviceName",
                    new Class[] { WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, String.class,
                            WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class });

            m.invoke(manager,channel, "AFNAN", new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                public void onSuccess() {

                    //Code for Success in changing name
                }

                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    //Code to be done while name change Fails
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
}
```

It causes a NullPointerException when I start the service from another activity because of this line:

```
manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a NullPointerException because it's trying to call `getSystemService` without a known context (the call should actually be `context.getSystemService(...)` ).

To use `getSystemService` in your Service you need to pass in a context somehow from an activity or fragment which creates and/or uses the service.